# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Keys are already present

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that accepts an array and renders it as a table using a predefined key.

```
<TableFromJson data={this.props.results.events} rowKey="eventID" />
```

TableFromJson.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    export class TableFromJson extends Component{

        render() {
            if (!this.props.data)
                return(<p>No data</p>);

            const key = this.props.rowKey;
            let columns = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
            let headerComponents = columns.map(col => <th>{col}</th>);

            let rowComponents = this.props.data.map((row) =>{
                let tdList = columns.map(col => <td>{row[col]}</td>);
                let htmlRow = <tr key={row[key]}>{tdList}</tr>;
                return htmlRow;
            });

            return (
                <Table bordered hover responsive striped>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>{headerComponents}</tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{rowComponents}</tbody>
                </Table>
            );
        }
    }

    TableFromJson.propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.array,
        key: PropTypes.string
    }
```

This renders a table as show below:

[image: Component with key shown in React Dev Tools]

The tr element already contains the key as you can see from the above screenshot from React Dev tools.

I'm getting the key error ("Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop") every time this component is rendered. What am I missing?

Comment: You should put a key on every element that is part of an array, i.e. `th`, `td`, `tr` in this case.

Comment: @root_access did you resolve your issue? If so - you can contribute as answering / accepting an answer / or giving some details. Otherwise - all the efforts were on vain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add keys to the children elements as well: `th`, `td`, as you already did it for `tr`.

Comment: I overlooked adding keys to the child elements, silly me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I helped you :)